# PHP to another server with the mysql database on it

Tags: php, sql

I have been trying to get data from a mysql server which is not on the same server as the php that retrieves the data.

The code for it is this:

```
    <?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
    ConnectTODB();

}
function ConnectToDB(){
    $servername = $_POST["servername"];
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $dbname = $_POST["dbname"];
    GetTableName($conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname));
}
function GetTableName($conn){
    $sqlGetTable = "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'";

    $connectionTABLE = $conn->query($sqlGetTable);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($connectionTABLE) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc(
            $connectionTABLE
        )) {
            $json[] = array(
                'TableName' => $row['TABLE_NAME'],
            );
        }
        $jsonstring = json_encode($json);
        echo $jsonstring;
    }
}
?>
```

the error i get is: 110 "Connection timed out"

and i have allowed the host in Remote Database Access Hosts.

- servername, i use the domain name
- password, the password of the mysql users password
- username i used the mysql username
- dbname is the mysql database name

i use x10hosting.com for the servers.

Any help will be greatly appreciated since i got it to work for the local database but not external servers.

Comment: post real code and not an image of it

Comment: Riggs... you're not helping lol!!

Comment: Wrong server name or port. Probably you need to specify the port.

Comment: Has the remote database servers user account been setup to allow remote connections

Comment: @Fred-ii- Agreed, but at least we can now see the code and the question in the same place

Comment: Dollars to donuts says you've got a firewall blocking you. Try [nmap](https://nmap.org/) to see if traffic is being filtered between hosts.

Comment: @Fred-ii- he fixed/posted the code

Comment: @JeffPuckettII *grazie* for the update ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have to guess here, since you did not provide any information about the servers involved in the problem.

Basically it is no problem to access a MySQL database on a different server. I've done that several times on servers within the same network (LAN) and even with servers that are on the internet (i.e. not within the same LAN).

The timeout message might indicate that the database server is under heavy load and cannot respond in a timely manner. However, it is more likely that some network setting (firewall, packet filter, etc.) do not allow to get a response from the server. See whether you can ping the DB server, and check with nmap whether the database port (usually 3306 for MySQL) is open on that server. Third option might be wrong credentials or wrong server name.